# Chosing validation based on submitted data in form

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to follow official docs and got stucked.

Here is a documentation page that I look to: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_based_validation.html

Thing, that I can't get - where did `Client::TYPE_PERSON` came from? I see no explanation there.
So, `Client` is Entity, but what is static field `TYPE_PERSON`?

Best regards!

Comment: It's a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, `Client::TYPE_PERSON` looks like its constant so you don't have magic values in code. Its just holding type of person so you can choose based on type of person which validation groups you want to use.

Comment: so, in this case, it's defined in the enitity class?

Comment: Yes, `Client::TYPE_PERSON` would be class constant